# how to make a bootable usb for ubuntu 16.04

Tags: usb

I want to use a 32g usb drive to install ubuntu 16.04 on my home lenovo. I am at my library because my lenovo cannot access internet.

Comment: Full guide [here](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows). Notice you will need to download the Rufus USB installer too. Get that and a copy of ubuntu, save into your USB, go home, and follow the instructions. I recommend you print the instructions page, or download the html.

Comment: Why is the automatic assumption that the question is about Windows?

Comment: See https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BurningIsoHowto, which include helps for Windows, MacOS, and Ubuntu host systems.

Answer (score 3):

I am assuming you are using windows. Here is a good tutorial from the official Ubuntu website.

http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows

As Ubuntu documentation states you should download the release your are wanting from their website.

[Ubuntu Downloads](http://www.ubuntu.com/download)

You will also need a program to create the bootable usb.
I and Ubuntu will recommend Rufus which can be found here:

[Rufus Downloads](https://rufus.akeo.ie/)

1. Open Rufus and select your USB stick in the 'Device' dropdown.
2. Click the CD Rom icon next to the 'FreeDOS' dropdown, then find your downloaded Ubuntu ISO and click 'Open' and then 'Start'
3. Click 'Yes' when it asks to download Syslinux software
4. Click 'OK' to write in ISO Image mode
5. Confirm that your USB stick is selected and then 'OK' to continue
6. When it is finished, just restart your computer and start using Ubuntu, or you can install Ubuntu

These steps are directly from the Ubuntu documentation mentioned above.