# setup from usb not disc

Tags: system-installation

I only have 700 MB CD.  Tried to save to USB but still asks to burn image CD and I don't have CD big enough.  Can I bypass burn image CD? how? if not how big does CD have to be? disc burner only has DVD drive option so I cant select USB as option even when USB in computer.  Computer has all necessary hardware called for by ubuntu.

Comment: Do you want to install Ubuntu as "dual boot" or would you like to erase windows and just install ubuntu? If you would like to erase windows and just install Ubuntu, you can install using a CD to install Ubuntu by using the Ubuntu minimal image which will fit on a CD but will only allow Ubuntu installation and does not contain a Live session to try Ubuntu without installing. The CD image can be found here: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/MinimalCD

Comment: Also, you cannot simply "save to a USB" you have to properly create a bootable USB device.

Comment: You need space of 2GB for live Ubuntu, so clearly you're not going to fit that onto a CD. A DVD has 4.7GB capacity so big enough. An 8GB flash drive (UFD) is ideal. You don't burn to a UFD. You extract files to it from the Ubuntu ISO

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bootable USB of Ubuntu Minimal CD](https://askubuntu.com/questions/689258/bootable-usb-of-ubuntu-minimal-cd). Even though the word USB is in the question's title, the Ubuntu minimal CD can, as its name suggests, also be burnt to an ordinary CD.

Answer (score 0):

There are plenty of guides to show you how to create a bootable USB. You can refer to one of them. e.g.  [how to make a bootable usb for ubuntu 16.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/804237/how-to-make-a-bootable-usb-for-ubuntu-16-04/804239)

Answer (score 0):

You can not create a bootable USB with a disc burner.

I would recommend using [Etcher](https://etcher.io/) to create a bootable USB, because it is open source, very easy to use, and available for almost any platform.

Alternatively you can follow the official Tutorials to create a bootable USB with Ubuntu on [Windows](https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-create-a-usb-stick-on-windows), [Ubuntu](https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-create-a-usb-stick-on-ubuntu) or [Mac](https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-create-a-usb-stick-on-macos).

Good Luck!